# trouble pushing to heroku using rails app

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

help would be much appreciated. for some reason, my push to heroku does not work even though my local version is working fine.

i'm deploying a rails app.

after a git push heroku, and heroku run rake db:migrate i get an application error on my website.

*EDIT* i put up the entire back trace

```
2012-03-13T20:49:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from 

/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-03-13T20:49:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-03-13T20:49:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-03-13T20:49:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-03-13T20:49:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-03-13T20:49:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-03-13T20:49:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-03-13T20:49:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-03-13T20:49:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-03-13T20:49:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-03-13T20:49:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-03-13T20:49:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-03-13T20:49:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-03-13T21:01:36+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET strong-sunrise-8468.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-03-13T21:03:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-03-13T21:03:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-03-13T21:03:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 43183`
2012-03-13T21:03:50+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-03-13T21:03:50+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:43183
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to sh

2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `block in replace_gem': bcrypt-ruby is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.1/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb:37:in `has_secure_password'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/user.rb:14:in `<class:User>'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/user.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `safe_constantize'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor

2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `require'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-03-13T21:03:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-03-13T21:03:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-03-13T21:03:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-03-13T21:04:38+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-03-13T21:04:44+00:00 app[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-03-13T21:04:45+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-03-13T21:04:45+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to complete
2012-03-13T21:04:52+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-03-13T21:04:58+00:00 app[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-03-13T21:04:58+00:00 app[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2012-03-13T21:04:59+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-03-13T21:05:04+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-03-13T21:05:04+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
2012-03-13T21:05:21+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET strong-sunrise-8468.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

i notice there are deprecation warnings, but im following the michael hartl book for beginners learning rails and he said to ignore them.

i did

```
heroku stack
```

and i am on the cedar stack as well

inside the environment.rb, the contents are...

```
1. # Load the rails application
2. require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
3. 
4. # Initialize the rails application
5. SampleApp::Application.initialize!
```

Comment: can you post the contents of environment.rb?

Comment: i added the environment.rb code onto the question

Comment: Please post the environment.rb file in such a way that we can see what's listed on line 5?

Comment: that was actually the whole file i posted. i added the line numbers on it

Comment: Is the backtrace above the entire thing?

Comment: i put up the entire backtrace now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this gem to Gemfile
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
probably your gem is using it on your local gems.
And don't forget to git add .

Comment: i stopped trying to fix my heroku app and have been doing it on my local machine. but i pushed today to heroku and it worked. the reason being...my bcrypt gem was in my development environment and not the "general"? group (like on the very top outside of the groups).

cannot believe it haha.
Thanks